# Load Variables from text file and if key exists in hashtable, use key value

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm trying to create a script, where the variables are outside of the PowerShell script. It's just a text file. In that file, we define server name, group names and their values. Group names meaning that the host has these strings in their hostname.

Hostnames have the higher priority, and Group names have the least priority. If neither is present, then there is a default value (inside the ps script).

The following `elseif` condition isn't working for me and I've tried a lot of other ways but could not get it working.

```
    elseif ($MachineName.Contains("$var.key")) { # Doesn't work. What can be used here?
    $foldername = ("$var.value")             # Doesn't work. What can be used here?
}
```

Content of `vars.txt`:

```
    #Groups
    DB=folder7

    #Hostnames
    server_JIRA_001=folder3
    server_DB_001=folder5
    server_DB_005=folder6
```

If a hostname is server_DB_006 it will use value "folder7" as it has the "DB" in their hostname, but if the hostname is server_DB_005 then it will use value "folder6"

Content of script.ps1

```
    $MachineName = "server_DB_006"
    $var = (Get-Content "c:\Users\user\Desktop\vars.txt" -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData) 

    if ($var.$MachineName -ne  $null) {
    # if hostname exists, then use its var.value
    $foldername = ($var.$MachineName)          # returns value of $var.hostname
    } elseif ($MachineName.Contains("$var.key")) { # Doesn't work. What can be used here? 
    # if no hostname defined, then search for group name and use its var.value
    $foldername = ("$var.value")                # Doesn't work. What can be used here? 
    } else {
    foldername = "default_folder"
    }
```

Comment: `$_` is not define anywhere.  It is created/populated by PowerShell in places such as `switch` statements and the pipeline, but not just in the middle of your script.

Comment: Oh it was part of my other testing where I tried a loop.  Editing the question again.

Comment: "$var.Key" is a problem.  You can either lose the quotes (they aren't doing anything) or use a subexpression "$($var.Key)"

Comment: Can you check the edited question,  I have added a comment.  What should I try?

Comment: Looping doesn't work when the values are not in order, because it sets wrong value

Comment: can you show a example of what your text file looks like

Comment: It's at the top.  "Content of vars.txt"

Comment: so "$var.key" doesnt make any sense. Basicly you are looking for literally for {HASHTABLE}.key : so what key are you looking for?, are you trying to loop through every key and see if the machine name contains it?

Comment: That's right.  Not just key  but it should also set value.  But looping means if the order isn't right then the last part of loop sets the value. Which is either right or wrong depending on the order.

Comment: so you need to get the keys in order as they are in the text file

Comment: That's something I don't want to do.  Is that the only way?  I wanted anyone to edit the vars.txt and don't care about the order.  I can't put strict rules, else I'll have to manage the vars.txt file. This will be part of a GPO. Hence I wanted another method where it's safe

Comment: Wouldn't sorting the vars.txt by key length and comparing from top down comply with your (inherent) rules?

Comment: I would say the best course of action would be to change `vars.txt` into an INI file and read that into a hash of hashes.

Comment: @LotPings How do I sort as key length or in descending order?

Comment: Excluding empty lines and comments: `(Get-Content .\vars.txt) -ne '' | Where-Object {$_.Substring(0,1) -ne '#'} | Sort-Object {$_.Length}` I'd stay with default ascending (`-Descending $False`)

Comment: Thanks I used the `Sort-Object {$_.Length} -Descending` to @ArcSet answer. It all works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can create a function who will bring back the key name if a  string contains it. It loops through the keys and checks the $Text to see if it contains the key text else returns false.

```
function StringContainsHashTableKey(){
    PARAM(
        [string]$Text,
        [hashtable]$HashTable
    )

    foreach($i in $Hashtable.Keys.GetEnumerator()){
        if($Text -like "*$i*" ){
            return $i
        }
    }
    return $false
}

$Var = Get-Content "c:\Users\user\Desktop\vars.txt" -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData

$MachineName = "server_DB_006"

$KeyMatch = StringContainsHashTableKey -Text $MachineName -HashTable $Var

if ($var.$MachineName -ne  $null) { #if hostname exists, then use its var.value
    $foldername = ($var.$MachineName) # returns value of $var.hostname
} 
# If no hostname defined, then search for group name and use its var.value
Elseif ($KeyMatch -ne $false) { # Doesn't work. What can be used here? 
    $foldername = $var.$KeyMatch
}
Else {
    $foldername = "default_folder"
}

$foldername
```

Comment: FYI the `return` keyword is superfluous in Powershell, at least for producing values. You can simply put `$i` and `$false` directly. (Same goes for the `$foldername` variable - you can remove that and output the values directly from the `if`)

Comment: The function seems to not work for me. Any suggestions? here is the error:- 

StringContainsHashTableKey : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'HashTable'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of 
type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\Untitled4.ps1:19 char:70
+ ... Match = StringContainsHashTableKey -Text $MachineName -HashTable $Var

Comment: +                                                                      ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [StringContainsHashTableKey], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,StringContainsHashTableKey

Thats' the rest of the error

Comment: I found a workaround for the error, but it seems the elseif condition still doesn't work for "server_DB_006".$keyMatch is false when it should be true since we have "DB=folder7". Can you double check?

Comment: the error is saying the variable you are using is not a hashtable.

Do $Var.GetType() and tell me the type that it shows

Comment: OK so whats happening is that when you do the Get-Content you are getting a array not a hashtable
instead use Get-Content -Raw.

Updated Post to reflect that change

Comment: Cool, It works now but It seems it is case sensitive. Only the foreach ($Text.Contains) is case sensitive. Can we make it not case sensitive? Try hostname `"server_db_006"` and it will return `default folder` instead of `folder7`

Comment: Changed the following and now its case insensitive. 

change `if($Text.Contains($i))`
 to         ` if($Text -like "*$i*" )`. There is asterisk but the comment can't show it. `$Text -like " * $i * "` remove extra spaces.

Comment: Is it possible to store hashtable Keys in descending order?  I see a problem,  the if condition picks the first value found. Example xyz and xyz1 both are  group name,  but xyz1 should have the higher priority.  Due to sorting,  it always picks xyz, thats why I want to store in descending order

Comment: Found the fix. `foreach($i in $Hashtable.Keys.GetEnumerator() | sort-Object {$_.Length} -Descending){`     I've edited the answer to fit this.